# Is there any difference between androidx paging and android-arch paging?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, androidx, android-paging

I have to set up pagination for my android project.
But I'm a little bit confused since there are two different libraries with same class names AndroidArchitectureComponents and AndroidX.

and in the documentation too I didn't found differences, methods are also the same.

What is the key difference between both of them?

Comment: "android architecture components" without the AndroidX was a way to add AAC to projects before AndroidX and Jetifier existed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

androidx is a new package structure rolled out by Google. Unlike the Support Library, AndroidX packages are separately maintained and updated. All new Support Library development will occur in the AndroidX library. So the androidx paging would contain new improvements and packaging structure would be different from the normal one.For using androidX packages you will have to migrate your project to androidX. Refer : [https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate]